# DAX IF ELSE statement performance issue

Tags: powerpivot, cube, dax

Sales := **CALCULATE**(
**IF**(**HASONEVALUE**('SalesTable'[Sales]),**CALCULATE**(**VALUES**('SalesTable'[Sales]))),
**LASTNONBLANK**('SalesTable'[Date],1))

The above query work fine. When I filter by month, it will shows my last sales 20000 for January, then when I filter 20170103, it will show me nothing because 20170103 has two values which is not valid. I would like to ask if there is any way I can improve this query for better browsing performance

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to get with that measure?

Comment: i would like to get the last non empty sales if it has one value

Comment: What is the reason for use `VALUES(SalesTable[Sales])`. Share sample data and your expected result and we could help you.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta update sample data as above

Comment: what value would you like to see if you filter 20170103 - 500 or 10000?  Detail what your expected result is. I think VALUES(SalesTable[Sales]) is decreasing the performance while browsing.

Comment: when i filter 20170103 it show not show anything